# fprintf produces different output

Tags: c, c++builder, borland-c++

I compiled the next program in C++ Builder 3 and C++ Builder 5, it produces a different output:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char filename[] = "C://fprintf-test.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a");

  fprintf(file, "%0*.0f\n", 7,  99999.00);
  fprintf(file, "%0*.0f\n", 7, -99999.00);
  fprintf(file, "%0*.0f\n", 7, -999.00);
  fprintf(file, "%0*.0f\n", 7, 999999.00);
  fprintf(file, "%0*.0f\n", 7, 9.00);

  return 0;
}
```

Output in C++ Builder 3:

```
0099999
-0099999
-0000999
0999999
0000009
```

Output in C++ Builder 5:

```
0099999
-099999
-000999
0999999
0000009
```

You can clearly see that the padding of 0 of the negative values differs. Why is this? Is this documented?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the super-contrived example to show this? Please think about simplifying things when asking, to cut down on the noise.

Comment: Because now people can test it for themselves, out of the box. But I will keep it in mind with my next question, thanks :-)

Comment: Sure, any question should ensure that. I guess I wonder: do you mean that you *don't* get this difference if you run a program whose `main()` consists of `{ printf("%07.0f\n", -999); return 0; }`, i.e. without the file, the other print statements, and the use of `*` for the field width?

Comment: It makes no difference if `printf` or `fprintf` is used and with or without the `*`.

Comment: Nicely formatted question.  It is certainly a C++ Builder 3 bug.

Comment: who is upgrading **to** C++Builder 5, in 2014? >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chux stated in the comments: this is probably a C++ Builder 3 bug. It is not documented.

If anyone has this problem, we fixed it like this:

```
fprintf(FileOut, "%0*.*f\n",
#if ( __BORLANDC__ >= 0x560 )
        paddingNumber,
#else
        paddingNumber < 0 ? paddingNumber - 1 : paddingNumber,
        paddingNumber )
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this on gcc :

```
// gcc -o test.exe test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("%0*.0f\n", 7,  99999.00);
  printf("%0*.0f\n", 7, -99999.00);
  printf("%0*.0f\n", 7, -999.00);
  printf("%0*.0f\n", 7, 999999.00);
  printf("%0*.0f\n", 7, 9.00);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the result :

```
0099999
-099999
-000999
0999999
0000009
```

printf documentation say :

> width : Minimum number of **characters** to be printed If the value to
>   be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded [...] The
>   value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

They speak about characters (minus is a character).

I don't know C++ builder. Look at printf C++ builder documentation difference V3/5.
(it's perhaps a bug in V3 ...)

Comment: Yes, that's what the output should be. But in BCB3 it produces a different output, which is not ANSI C compliant imo. I'm wondering why it is not, and where this is documented.

Comment: Odds are its not documented BCB3 has a bug and BCB5 fixes it.  Not all bug fixes were documented.  And to try and find documentation for a compiler that old will be very difficult.

Comment: There seem to be no BCB3 reports on QC .. I don't even think QC existed back then